# creating a keyword dict with keywords and filenames from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why I  get this error when I try to test this function. Can anyone please help me fix this?

d[keywords] = [filename, keywords]
builtins.TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I want my end result to look like this.
{'keyword": ['filename1', 'filename2'...]}
where the filenames are ones which have keyword in their list of keywords

Here is the file:

```
images/skating.jpg,East York Arena,2014.11.03,Shea skating.,skating,Shea,boy
images/sunglasses.jpg,High Park,2013.02.03,Cool guy.,Shea,sunglasses,happy
images/skating2.jpg,East York Arena,2014.11.03,Shea skating 
again!,skating,Shea

def create_keyword_dict(open_file):
'''(file) -> dict of {str: list of str}
Given an open csv file with the format:
filename,location,date,caption,keywords,keywords, ...
return a new dictionary where the key is a keyword and each value
is a list of filenames that have that keyword in their list of keywords.
'''
d = {}
for line in open_file:
    new_d = line.split(',')
    filename = new_d[0]
    keywords = new_d[5:]
    if filename not in d:
        d[keywords] = [filename, keywords]
return d
```

Comment: You're trying to use a `list` as dictionary key, which doesn't work. Also, you should use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the standard library to read/parse CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a list as a dictionary key. The type you use as a key needs to be hashable (this is what the `TypeError: unhashable type` refers to.

Instead of using a list, you'll need to sort and group your files by *single* keywords, and use those as the keys - this has the added benefit of being able to search the list by a single keyword, instead of requiring you to have all the keywords for a file to be able to find it. Something like this would work:

```
for line in open_file:
    new_d = line.split(',')
    filename = new_d[0]
    keywords = new_d[5:]
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword not in d:
            d[keyword] = [filename]
        else:
            d[keyword].append(filename)
```

Comment: what does the last line mean?

Comment: But d[keyword] is still a key, so isn't it a dict?

Comment: No, `d[keyword]` is a list. This loops over every keyword in the file's keywords list. If they're not already in `d`, it adds a list under `d[keyword]` containing the filename. If they're already there, it adds the filename to the existing list.